# why is psychopy.visual.MovieStim3 so slow in my use case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psychopy

Currently I would like to continually play movies in a loop from different filepaths using python 3.6, psychopy 1.90.2. The filepaths are listed in a csv file and each filepath has common ancestors but has a different parent directory and filename. e.g. '/media/michael/shared_network_drive/dataset/training/jumping/man_jumps_through_hoop3342.mp4' and '/media/michael/shared_network_drive/dataset/training/shouting/h555502.mp4'.

Currently there is a very large delay when creating the visual.MovieStim3 object which results in a large delay before every video. Here is the code so far:

```
def play_videos(csv_file, vid_location='/media/michael/shared_network_drive/dataset/training/'):
    # Open a window
    win = visual.Window([400,400])
    #open csv file and cycle through each video
    for vid, label, val1, val2 in csv.reader(open(csv_file, 'r')):
        glob_vid_path = vid_location + vid
        # Define a MovieStim3 object
        mov = visual.MovieStim3(win, glob_vid_path, flipVert=False, flipHoriz=False)
        # Loop through each frame of the video
        while mov.status != visual.FINISHED:
            mov.draw()
            win.flip()        
win.close()
```

Why is the delay so long and how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those with similar problems; the delay is caused by the location of the videos in a shared drive. Placing the videos on the home drive, or even an external hard-drive solved the problem.

Comment: @Michael MacAskill Stackoverflow returns the message "you can accept your own answer tomorrow". I will make sure that I do. Thanks, Michael.